# Password encryption in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have one login page. when user give user name and password, i want to encrypt the password and send it to the server. I am using angular js application so i want to write that code also in angular. Please

Comment: Are you looking for https ?

Comment: @KISHAN PATI I would like to suggest you dont use angular to encrypt your password
Use your backend technology java or what ever you are using

Comment: Don't encrypt it, send it over HTTPS and let backend do its job.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: You can use `angularjs-crypto` to encrypt and decrypt

Comment: What would you achieve by encrypting the password before sending it to the server? What scenario are you trying to mitigate or are you doing this simply because it sounds cool?

Comment: In my project we are separating our backend code and frontend code. In frontend we are just making some api calls to get the value and so it in the views. For that only before sending the value in $http post i want to encypt it.

Answer (score 5):

Use HTTPS to send it to the server, then encrypt/decrypt it server-side. For security reason, you don't want the frontend to do any encryption, that could led to serious security flaws.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use https for sending secured data and encrypting on server.
If you still want to encrypt in client code, then you can use SHA256 or SHA1 or MD5. Many are available. Angular-crypto provide many JS.
Include reference to JS in html page and below line in controller.

```
 CryptoJS.SHA1($scope.newCustomer.password)
```

For good security, on server side, SALT your hashed passwords.

Comment: None of "SHA256 or SHA1 or MD5" are encryption, they are one-way cryptographic hash functions. Also: Just adding a salt to a hash function does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score -2):

Using following ngEncryption factory you can encrypt your data in Controller.js file and pass it to apicontroller. I am using Public-Private key to encrypt data for encryption/decryption.These key can be generated in Session_Start() event in Global.asax.cs file.

```
app.factory
('ngEncryption', function () {
    return {
        encrypt: function (dataForEncrypt) {
            jsRequest = {};

            var str = dataForEncrypt;
            var xmlParams = $.cookie('ClientPublicKey');
            // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            var rsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            var reqArray = [];
            var reqArraySize = 200;
            if (str.length < reqArraySize) {
                var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
                // Import parameters from xml.
                rsa.FromXmlString(xmlParams);
                // Encrypt data (use OAEP padding).          

                var encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(data, true);
                // Convert encrypted data to Base64.
                var encryptedString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes)
                // Replace plain password with encrypted data.
                reqArray.push(encryptedString);
                //break;
            }
            else {
                var MaxCounterHeader = parseInt(Math.ceil(parseFloat(str.length / 200)));

                for (i = 0; i < MaxCounterHeader; i++) {
                    var newstring = str.substr(0, str.length > 200 ? 200 : str.length);
                    var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newstring);
                    rsa.FromXmlString(xmlParams);
                    var encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(data, true);
                    // Convert encrypted data to Base64.
                    var encryptedString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes)
                    reqArray.push(encryptedString);
                    str = str.replace(newstring, '');
                }
            }
            return JSON.stringify(reqArray);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I get "ReferenceError: System is not defined", on line new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();

Comment: You need to add reference of system.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll